# Performance of fpdf image in php7.4

Tags: php, performance, pdf, fpdf

We use fpdf to create pdf documents. With the Image function we place an image on a pdf. In version php7.3 an image that we used a lot took 0,25 sec to place, to our surprise in version php7.4 it went up to 0,7 sec. We started looking for the exact spot this caused. It turned out to be the following routine in the Image function:

first

```
// Read image data block
$data .= $this->_readstream($f,$n);
```

later on

```
$len = 4*$w;
for($i=0;$i<$h;$i++)
{
    $pos = (1+$len)*$i;
    $color .= $data[$pos];
    $alpha .= $data[$pos];
    $line = substr($data,$pos+1,$len);
    $color .= preg_replace('/(.{3})./s','$1',$line);
    $alpha .= preg_replace('/.{3}(.)/s','$1',$line);
}
```

For an image of w x h of let's say 1200 x 600 pixels quite a bit happens here. The performance issues exist in the for-loop.

Our questions are then

1. Why is this a lot slower in php7.4 than php7.3 ?
2. Exactly which statement causes this and why?
3. What can be done about this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the contents of the `substrate` function? Are you using the latest version of fPDF which is 1.82?

Comment: Yes, We are using version 1.82. The word 'substrate' should have been the normal php 'substr' in my post. Apologies for the inconvenience

Comment: Is the [`pcre.jit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php) setting disabled on your PHP 7.4?

Comment: PCRE JIT Support: not compiled in. What effect does this have?

Comment: Was it enabled on PHP 7.3?

Comment: Yes, on PHP 7.3 it was enabled.

Comment: Then you have the explanation.